# Save new Contact to contact list in List Manager

Tags: list-manager

I work with `Sitecore 9.1`, and I added new contact list from list manager my new list name `Subscript_list`, I want to save contact information (Email, first name, and Last name) programmatically, I created Form contains the fields (Email, first name, and Last name),I found many articles, but the articles focus to save data to `XConnect` and send email using `EXM` Module.

How can I save data from my form directly to my new contact list?

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Contact List is just a list of contacts from xConnect. If you update contact in xConnect, it will be updates as well when you access it via contact list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically add contact to a contact list in Sitecore 9.0u1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-programatically-add-contact-to-a-contact-list-in-sitecore-9-0u1)

Comment: Take a look on my previous answer to different question which is a I think a duplicate of this one -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/10814/2056

Answer (score 2):

You should create new Contact and add a new subscription to `ListSubscriptions facet`.

**Create contact:**

```
       public async Task<bool> CreateContact(
            string source,
            string identifier,
            string firstName,
            string lastName,
            string email)
        {
            using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    IdentifiedContactReference reference = new IdentifiedContactReference(source, identifier);

                    var contactTask = client.GetAsync(
                        reference,
                        new ContactExpandOptions()
                    );

                    Contact existingContact = await contactTask;

                    if (existingContact != null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    var contactIdentifiers = new[]
                    {
                        new ContactIdentifier(source, identifier, ContactIdentifierType.Known),

                    };

                    Contact contact = new Contact(contactIdentifiers);

                    var personal = new PersonalInformation
                    {
                        FirstName = firstName,
                        LastName = lastName
                    };


                    var preferredEmail = new EmailAddress(email, true);
                    var emails = new EmailAddressList(preferredEmail, "Work");

                    client.AddContact(contact);
                    client.SetPersonal(contact, personal);
                    client.SetEmails(contact, emails);

                    await client.SubmitAsync();

                    return true;
                }
                catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
                {
                    _logService.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Subscribe contact to list:**

```
 public async Task<bool> SubscribeContact(string source, string identifier, Guid listId)
        {
            using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    IdentifiedContactReference reference = new IdentifiedContactReference(source, identifier);

                    var contactTask = client.GetAsync(
                        reference,
                        new ContactExpandOptions(
                            ListSubscriptions.DefaultFacetKey
                            )
                    );

                    Contact contact = await contactTask;

                    if (contact == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (contact.Identifiers.All(x => x.Source != "ListManager"))
                        client.AddContactIdentifier(contact, new ContactIdentifier("ListManager", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ContactIdentifierType.Known));

                    var subscriptions = contact.ListSubscriptions() ?? new ListSubscriptions();
                    var subscription = new ContactListSubscription(DateTime.UtcNow, true, listId);
                    subscriptions.Subscriptions.Add(subscription);
                    client.SetListSubscriptions(contact, subscriptions);   

                    await client.SubmitAsync();

                    return true;
                }
                catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
                {
                    _logService.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you please tell me what the value of parameters (source and identifier )

public async Task<bool> SubscribeContact(string source, string identifier, Guid listId)

Comment: Contact can have several sources for identification. In your case, you can just create a constant for source "public const string IdentificationSource = "MyApplication"; " and use it instead of 'source'. As identifier you can use Email for example (or any other unique identifier of user).   Something like " new ContactIdentifier("MyApplication", "testUser@gmail.com", ContactIdentifierType.Known)". Source and identifier will be used by you in future to retrieve Contact from xConnect, or to identify user on your website "Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs(source, identifier)".

Comment: Thank you so much, I will use this code to Creating a custom submit action for my Form , I used Sitecore Forms 
Thanks you again!

Comment: how  can I call the 2 task (Create contact) and  (Subscribe contact to list), inside controller ActionResult ?