# How to save contacts to a list in Sitecore Forms 9

Tags: wffm, sitecore-forms

In the Web Forms for Marketers module of version 9, there is an option in the submit action to add contacts to a list (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/web-forms-for-marketers/en/use-save-actions-to-add-contacts-to-a-contact-list.html). However, I can't find the same option in Sitecore Forms version 9.

Wondering any way I can make this option available in Sitecore Forms too ?

Comment: Please check this first - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18722/save-new-contact-to-contact-list-in-list-manager-sitecore-9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of box functionality in Sitecore 9 forms. There can be two possible solutions:

1. Create custom submit action to add a contact in List
2. Trigger a goal on form submit and in Marketing Automation, based on goal trigger, add that contact in the list

[image]